# Multiple curves in ggplot2 with same independent variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sequence of points in the x-axis for each of which there are two points in the y-axis.

```
x<-seq(8.5,10,by=0.1)
y<-c(0.9990276914, 0.9973015358, 0.9931704801, 0.9842176288, 0.9666471511, 0.9354201700, 0.8851624615, 0.8119131899, 0.7152339504, 0.5996777045, 0.4745986612, 0.3519940258, 0.2431610835, 0.1556738744, 0.0919857178, 0.0500000000, 0.0249347645, 0.0113838852, 0.0047497169, 0.0018085048, 0.0006276833)
y1<-c(9.999998e-01,9.999980e-01,9.999847e-01,9.999011e-01,9.994707e-01,9.976528e-01,9.913453e-01, 9.733730e-01, 9.313130e-01, 8.504646e-01, 7.228116e-01, 5.572501e-01,3.808638e-01,2.264990e-01, 1.155286e-01, 5.000000e-02, 1.821625e-02, 5.554031e-03, 1.410980e-03, 2.976926e-04, 5.203069e-05)
```

I would now like to create two curves in ggplot2. This is quite easy to accomplish in the normal way in R. The result is in the plot below. I am not sure, however, how to do that in ggplot2. For just one curve, I can use

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-qplot(x,y,geom="line")
```

Could you please help me generalise the above? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.
[image]

Comment: there are some examples in `?geom_line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roland also pointed out first you should fix the length of `x`. A possible solution using the [`reshape2`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/) package:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

x<-seq(8.5,10,length.out = 21)
y<-c(0.9990276914, 0.9973015358, 0.9931704801, 0.9842176288, 0.9666471511, 0.9354201700, 0.8851624615, 0.8119131899, 0.7152339504, 0.5996777045, 0.4745986612, 0.3519940258, 0.2431610835, 0.1556738744, 0.0919857178, 0.0500000000, 0.0249347645, 0.0113838852, 0.0047497169, 0.0018085048, 0.0006276833)
y1<-c(9.999998e-01,9.999980e-01,9.999847e-01,9.999011e-01,9.994707e-01,9.976528e-01,9.913453e-01, 9.733730e-01, 9.313130e-01, 8.504646e-01, 7.228116e-01, 5.572501e-01,3.808638e-01,2.264990e-01, 1.155286e-01, 5.000000e-02, 1.821625e-02, 5.554031e-03, 1.410980e-03, 2.976926e-04, 5.203069e-05)

df <- data.frame(x, y, y1)

df <- melt(df, id.var='x')


ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable))+geom_line()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Changing the linetype and legend:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable, linetype=variable)) + geom_line()

g <- g +  scale_linetype_discrete(name="Custom legend name",
                              labels=c("Curve1", "Curve2"))

g <- g + guides(color=FALSE)

print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please also tell me how I could change the lines so that one is normal and the other one is dotted? And the legend of course.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the lengths of your x and y values don't match. Combine your data and use a grouping variable:

```
x<-seq(8.5,10, length.out = 21)
DF <- data.frame(x=rep(x, 2), y=c(y, y1), g=c(y^0, y1^0*2))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=factor(g), linetype=factor(g))) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Oh sorry for that, I missed a point. Thank you for your response.